# Visual Studio file nesting aspx - aspx.py

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ironpython

Is it possible to have .aspx  and .aspx.py (IronPython codefile) nested underneath aspx files in VS 2010 ? I've seen some people added Windows registry entries for Visual Studio so other files would show up as nested underneath aspx, but I've no idea how to do it for IronPython if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution just in case someone needs the same, for websites which is what I needed (for web applications is easier because there's an installable tool)

Add a registry entry key ".py" in

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles.aspx